# `cryptsetup luksDump` or `cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup` generate no output

Tags: luks

The Luks volume works fine regarding mounting it, reading from and writing to it. But when It try to create a backup for its header, with `cryptsetup luksDump` or `cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup` I get nothing, not even an error message.

I tried under sudo `cryptsetup luksDump /dev/mapper/<device>` and `cryptsetup luksDump /media/user/partition`. Tried the unmounted volume too.

```
sudo cryptsetup -v luksDump /media/<user>/LUKS
Command failed with code -4 (wrong device or file specified).

sudo cryptsetup -v luksDump /media/<user>/LUKS/
Command failed with code -4 (wrong device or file specified).

sudo cryptsetup -v luksDump /dev/mapper/LUKS
Command failed with code -1 (wrong or missing parameters).

sudo cryptsetup -v luksDump /dev/mapper/LUKS/
Device /dev/mapper/LUKS/ doesn't exist or access denied.
Command failed with code -4 (wrong device or file specified).
```

and

```
cryptsetup -v isLuks /dev/mapper/LUKS 
Command failed with code -1 (wrong or missing parameters).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The errors you are showing seem to indicate you are running your commands against the *mapping names* (search `man 8 cryptsetup` for "mapping" to see what it refers to), i.e. the decrypted devices created by the device mapper, and not against the actual encrypted ones.

For instance, if you open a LUKS device using the command

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda2 sda2_crypt
```

you will find the device `sda2_crypt` (the *mapping name*) in `/dev/mapper`, but you will have to run

```
cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda2
```

to dump the header located on the encrypted device.